# Web page with parallax lags on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parallax

I'm currently developing a [web page](http://undertaleita.net/tealrabarbaro.php) with a scrolling parallax effect (Stellar.js) on the header and three other sections of the site: however, scrolling them causes lag, especially at the top of the page.

I've already tried to reduce the background images' size by using compression, but it hasn't made too much difference; removing the blur effect didn't solve the problem, either (it did reduce the lag, but it still wasn't smooth enough).

The website runs pretty well on Firefox (W10), with almost no frame drops, but there's quite some lag on Chrome (both Windows and OS X) and Safari.

There's a few JS scroll-triggered scripts running, but I don't know if those may be the cause. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can the other scroll events be debounced?

Comment: I think so, but what would the JS for that be like? (I'm not really experienced with that)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're going to want to do is throttle scroll events. Debouncing events means an event can't fire again until after a certain amount of time. Throttling events means that the event can only fire so much per period of time.

Here's function to throttle events (credit: http://sampsonblog.com/749/simple-throttle-function)

```
// Create the listener function
function throttle (callback, limit) {
    var wait = false;                 // Initially, we're not waiting
    return function () {              // We return a throttled function
        if (!wait) {                  // If we're not waiting
            callback.call();          // Execute users function
            wait = true;              // Prevent future invocations
            setTimeout(function () {  // After a period of time
                wait = false;         // And allow future invocations
            }, limit);
        }
    }
 }
```

To use it just do something like this:

```
function callback () {
    console.count("Throttled");
}

window.addEventListener("scroll", throttle( callback, 200 ));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It gave the scrolling a little speed boost, but there's still some lag. I don't know if anything can be done for that.

Comment: The things I would look at around js performance in general are image size, number of event listeners, frequency of triggering event handlers (thus we throttle), number of dom nodes, and frequency of dom manipulation.  This isn't intended as self promotion, but I wrote something for parallax whose source may help you: https://github.com/winhowes/parallax-container/